# How can I get a svelte app to update fields correctly?

Tags: svelte

I have a svelte application (see [repl here](https://svelte.dev/repl/2d0661f1b1534f59900e46a05cfa6a63?version=3.46.4))

I want to be able to select a car from the select box. The colour field should update with the default colour for the car. This can then be overridden by the user in the *colour* input, and the display updated

This works for the first car selected, but after that the colour is always for the previous car.

What am I doing wrong?

**App.svelte**

```
<script>
    import DisplayMessage from './display.svelte'
    import Car from './cars.svelte'
    let car = 'default car'
    let colour = 'default colour'
$: message = displayCar(car, colour)

function displayCar(car, colour) {
    if (!car || !colour) {
        return 'No car selected'
    }
    return `The ${car} is ${colour}`
}
</script>

<DisplayMessage  bind:display_message={message}/>
<Car bind:car_name={car} bind:colour={colour}/>
```

**cars.svelte**

```
<script>
    let makes  = {Audi: 'black', BMW: 'blue', Jaguar: 'green'}
    let cars = []
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(makes)) {
        cars.push(key);
    }

    export let car_name = '';
    export let colour = '';
    $: colour = makes[car_name]
</script>

<div class="double-column">
    <div>car</div>
    <select id="car-select" bind:value={car_name}>
        {#each cars as car}
            <option value={car}>
                {car}
            </option>
        {/each}
    </select>
</div>
<input type="text" bind:value={colour} placeholder="colour"/>
```

**display.svlete**

```
<div id="display-message">{display_message}</div>

<script>
    export let display_message = ''
</script>
```

Comment: why do you do `bind:display_message={message}` ? that one is messing up because it is trying to override your message, the flow is a bit hard to follow though.  Just remove the `bind:` because you likely don't need it

Comment: That does it - do you want to answer and I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `bind:display_message={message}`

This creates a two way relation between `display_message` and `message` which is somehow messed up. There are plenty of updates happening at once, a new car means a new string, a new colour means a new string, and your binding means another string is being send back.

It's best to be extra carefull when using `bind:` and especially not bind to reactive variables because the data flow is fragile (on top it doesn't really make sense because the reactive variable is dependent on variables in your parent component)

Since you (very likely) do not need the two way binding just remove `bind:this` here and it will work fine.